# How to automatically rename a Java method in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying to rename a method in my Eclipse Java project, but it seems to be renaming *every* method which has the same name. (Perhaps I'm misunderstanding what this feature is for - maybe it's just using sed?)

Here is a simplified example:

```
    public class C1 {
        interface Listener {
            void f();
        }

        public C2.Listener c2l = new C2.Listener() {
            public void f() {
            }
        };
    }
```

```
    public class C2 {
        interface Listener {
            void f();
        }
    }
```

If I select the `f` method in `C2`, and select "rename" from the "refactor" menu to rename it to `g`, `C1.Listener.f` is also renamed, resulting with `C1` being changed to this:

```
    public class C1 {
        interface Listener {
            void g();
        }

        public C2.Listener c2l = new C2.Listener() {
            public void g() {
            }
        };
    }
```

I expected it to be changed to this:

```
    public class C1 {
        interface Listener {
            void f();
        }

        public C2.Listener c2l = new C2.Listener() {
            public void g() {
            }
        };
    }
```

Is there a way to make it only rename `C2.Listener.f`?

I tried in Eclipse Helios and Android Development Tools 22.3.0.

Comment: You should post this on the Eclipse boards.

Comment: You're sure there is no relation between the `C1.Listener` and `C2.Listener` interfaces? If so, this is a bug in Eclipse where it's getting name scopes wrong and should be filed.

Comment: First rename C1 Listener to Listener2, Then rename your function, then rename Listener2 to Listener... but you really should give different interfaces different names.

Comment: By the way, doing your original approach works fine in Kepler SP1.

Comment: @Dog, please stop creating the `ide-bug` [meta tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

Comment: @Charles: Then should I also stop using the compiler-bug tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems like a bug in Eclipse and seems to happen on Kepler too. Even so you can work around it by following the steps below:

Goto Preferences > Java. On that page in under the header "Refactor Java Code", uncheck the option "Rename in editor without dialog"

Now when you Refactor it gives you an option to Preview your changes and here you can uncheck the box to apply the changes to C1.Listener()